# Optional parse from stream with State monad

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm new to cats. I'm creating `State` instances to handle deserialisation of types from a byte stream. e.g.

```
  val int: State[Seq[Byte], Int] = State[Seq[Byte], Int] {
    case bs if bs.length >= 4 =>
      bs.drop(4) -> ByteBuffer.wrap(bs.take(4).toArray).getInt
    case _ => throw new EOFException()
  }
```

I have implemented a parser of `Option[Int]` in terms of the above, like so:

```
val unit: State[Seq[Byte], Unit] = State[Seq[Byte], Unit](_ -> Unit)

val optInt: State[Seq[Byte], Option[Int]] = int.flatMap(i => 
  if (i == 1) int.map(Some(_)) else unit.map(_ => None)
)
```

I feel that I've missed a trick here, as the implementation seems too verbose. Can I write this more succinctly? Can I do away with needing to define `unit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say that's too verbose, but I'd do two tricks with this:

1. Replace conditional with pattern matching function
2. Use `State.pure` instead of manually creating/transforming `State` values such as your `unit`.

---

```
val optInt: State[Seq[Byte], Option[Int]] = int.flatMap {
  case 1 => int.map(Some(_))
  case _ => State.pure(None)
}
```